# Databinding form data set to list box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have added Dataset from  database. From dataset values are loading and from Dataset to list Box. It is not loading. I got exception like

```
object instance Null reference exception
```

Here is the code I have, please correct error.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["PageJobseekerRegisIds"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["PageJobseekerRegisId"] = ViewState["PageJobseekerRegisIds"].ToString();
    ds = objJobseekerEdu.GetIndusrtries();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        ddlIndustry.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["industry_type"].ToString();
        ddlIndustry.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["industry_id"].ToString();
        ddlIndustry.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlIndustry.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works :)

```
DataSet ds = objJobseekerEdu.GetIndusrtries();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        ddlIndustry.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlIndustry.DataTextField ="industry_type";
        ddlIndustry.DataValueField ="industry_id";        
        ddlIndustry.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: OP still might get null reference error...but your point is also good